# Compare 2 excel columns if their corresponding ID's match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 4 excel columns. I want to compare if 2 columns (Type) match if their corresponding IDs match. ID is unique.

Example

```
ID Type ID Type

1   A   2   B

2   B   3   C

3   C   4   A

4   D   6   F

5   A
```

Output desired is result column if match found or no.

Which function should I use. I tried vlookup but I don't know how to check only their IDs match.

Comment: you should use `=Match( ...., 0)`

Comment: Tried =MATCH(C:C,A:A,0) but where do I put condition that ID should match

Answer (score 0):

If these are in columns `A` through `D` you could use in Column `E`:

```
=if(vlookup(C1, A:B, 2, false)=D1, "Matches", "Doesn't Match")
```

This will look up the C1 value into the A:B list and see if the corresponding Type matches when the ID's match.